# Unable to link to libgfortran.a

Tags: c, cuda, linker, gfortran

I have gfortran installed on my system and the file `libgfortran.a` can be found at `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/`. Using `nm` I made sure that the function `_gfortran_compare_string` is defined in there:

```
$ nm /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libgfortran.a | grep _gfortran_compare_string
```

Returns

```
0000000000000000 T _gfortran_compare_string
0000000000000000 T _gfortran_compare_string_char4
```

But, the linker of my CUDA-C program throws errors:

```
/usr/local/cuda-6.0/bin/nvcc --cudart static -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6 -L/home/chung/lapack-3.5.0 -link -o  "pQP"  ./src/pQP.o   -lgfortran -llapacke -llapack -lcublas -lblas -lcurand
nvcc warning : The 'compute_10' and 'sm_10' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release.
/home/chung/lapack-3.5.0/liblapack.a(ilaenv.o): In function `ilaenv_':
ilaenv.f:(.text+0x81): undefined reference to `_gfortran_compare_string'
```

and later on another error, again related to libgfortran:

```
/home/chung/lapack-3.5.0/liblapack.a(xerbla.o): In function `xerbla_':
xerbla.f:(.text+0x49): undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write'
xerbla.f:(.text+0x54): undefined reference to `_gfortran_string_len_trim'
xerbla.f:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
xerbla.f:(.text+0x76): undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_integer_write'
xerbla.f:(.text+0x7e): undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write_done'
xerbla.f:(.text+0x87): undefined reference to `_gfortran_stop_string'
```

But, again using nm, I found that `_gfortran_st_write`, etc are defined in libgfortran.a.

Links: [Complete log](https://gist.github.com/alphaville/0e2342b2e85c8b5ab33f) and [source code](https://github.com/alphaville/pQP).

**Note:** Lapack makes use of libgfortran. I recently installed lapack and ran all the tests and they all passed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change the order in which you specify static libraries to the linker. If you do something like this:

```
nvcc --cudart static -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6 \
-L/home/chung/lapack-3.5.0 -link -o  "pQP"  ./src/pQP.o  \ 
-llapacke -llapack -lcublas -lblas -lcurand -lgfortran
```

You should find it will work.

The underlying reason (and this is a trait of the gcc/gnu toolchain and not anything to do with nvcc) is that linking dependency lists for static libraries are parsed from left to right by the gnu linker. If you specify a static library *before* any library which depends on it, it will be skipped because it has no dependencies in the link list *at the point in processing when it is first encountered*.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a million! I'll be eternally indebted!